# SQL Date Range comparison Clash for Resource Bookings Repeated Results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, date-range

I am querying a booking table to see if I have a Resource Clash.
The query joins to the same table twice similar to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727467/578451

However I get duplicate results returned

i.e. Booking 1 Clashes with Booking 2 & Booking 2 Clashes with Booking 1:

```
2 records returned..

booking_1_id|booking_2_id
1           |2
2           |1
```

Somehow I need to remove one of the (near) duplicates.
GROUP BY is not enough.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (

-- your complete query here

) AS baseview
WHERE booking_1_id<booking_2_id;
```

Comment: I am sure there is, but since you didn't post your original query, I have no way to modify it ;-)