# SQL query from 3 tables returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question in an assignment that I have spent in excess of 40 hours trying to solve.
I get the correct answer when joining two of the tables together, but when I add the third - I lose a row and count is incorrect.

This finds the correct answer:

```
use prime_minister_2013;
select ministry.pm_name, count(*) AS Number_times_PM, ministry.min_begin, ministry.party,deputy_pm.deputy_name
from ministry, deputy_pm
where deputy_pm.min_nr = ministry.min_nr
and ministry.party <> 'ALP'
and min_begin < '1930-01-01'
group by ministry.pm_name;
```

but when I try to add the third table containing who was the Governor General when they are elected it loses one of the rows (a PM) and the count on 2 of the rows doubles.

I am assuming I have the joins/& or grouping incorrect!

```
use prime_minister_2013;
select ministry.pm_name, count(*) AS Number_times_PM, ministry.min_begin, ministry.party,deputy_pm.deputy_name, gg_title, gg_name
from ministry
join deputy_pm
on deputy_pm.min_nr = ministry.min_nr
join governor_general
on governor_general.pm_name = ministry.pm_name 
and ministry.party <> 'ALP'
and min_begin < '1930-01-01'
group by ministry.pm_name;
```

Any suggestion greatly appreciated - due 25/9/13

---

Thank you everyone for your comments – please find samples of tables below:

**Table: ministry**

```
min_nr  pm_name party   min _begin
1   Barton E    Protectionist   1/01/1901
15  Bruce S M   Nationalist 9/02/1923
27  Chifley J B ALP 13/07/1945
28  Chifley J B ALP 1/11/1946
9   Cook J  Liberal 24/06/1913
24  Curtin J J A    ALP 7/10/1941
25  Curtin J J A    ALP 21/09/1943
```

**Table: Deputy PM**

```
min_nr  deputy _ name   party
1   Deakin A    Protectionist
2   Lyne W J    Protectionist
3   Hughes W M  ALP
4   McLean A    Protectionist
5   Isaacs I A  Protectionist
6   Hughes W M  ALP
7   Cook J  Free Trade
8   Hughes W M  ALP
9   Forrest J   Liberal
```

**Table: Governor Generals**

```
GG_name GG_title    GG _begin   GG _end pm_name
Hope J A L  7th Earl of Hopetoun    1/01/1901   9/01/1903   Barton E
Tennyson H  2nd Baron Tennyson  9/01/1903   21/01/1904  Barton E
Northcote H S   Baron Northcote 21/01/1904  9/09/1908   Deakin A
Ward W H    2nd Earl of Dudley  9/09/1908   31/07/1911  Deakin A
Denman T    3rd Baron Denman    31/07/1911  18/05/1914  Fisher A
Munro Ferguson, R C Rt Hon Sir  18/05/1914  6/10/1920   Cook J
Forster H W Baron Forster   6/10/1920   8/10/1925   Hughes W M
Baird J L   Baron Stonehaven    8/10/1925   22/01/1931  Bruce S M
Isaacs I A  Rt Hon Sir  22/01/1931  23/01/1936  Scullin J H
Hore-Ruthven A G A  Brig. Gen, Baron Gowrie 23/01/1936  30/01/1945  Lyons J A
Gloucester H W F A  HRH Prince, Duke of Gloucester  30/01/1945  11/03/1947  Curtin J J A
```

---

In response to Space Dogs suggestions - i tried this:

```
use prime_minister_2013;
select ministry.pm_name AS 'PM Name', DATE_FORMAT (ministry.min_begin,'%Y') As 'Ministry Started', ministry.party AS 'Party', deputy_pm.deputy_name AS 'Deputy PM Name', COUNT(DISTINCT ministry.min_begin) AS 'Number of times PM',  gg_title AS 'GG Title', gg_name AS 'GG Name'
from ministry
join deputy_pm
on deputy_pm.min_nr = ministry.min_nr
join governor_general
on governor_general.pm_name = ministry.pm_name 
and ministry.party <> 'ALP'
and min_begin < '1930-01-01'
group by ministry.pm_name;
```

This gave me:

```
Barton E    1901    Protectionist   Deakin A    1   2nd Baron Tennyson  Tennyson H
Bruce S M   1923    Nationalist Page  C G   1   Baron Stonehaven    Baird J L
Cook J  1913    Liberal Forrest J   1   Rt Hon Sir  Munro Ferguson, R C
Deakin A    1909    Protectionist   Cook J  3   Baron Northcote Northcote H S
Hughes W M  1916    National Labor  Pearce G F  3   Baron Forster   Forster H W
```

which is getting there - but still missing the PM that doesn't have a GG

Comment: What do the tables/data look like?

Comment: create a sqlfiddle plz

Comment: Please give sample data with your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help without seeing the data, but you ask for suggestions so here's what I would do.

First, check the data -- you say some rows disappear and the count on other doubles -- so that implies that for some PM there was no Governor General in the data, and for others there were two. You should try much simpler queries, just selecting a few things (no group or COUNT function) joining each of the two tables separately so you can understand the data.

You're doing an `INNER JOIN` (which `JOIN` is equivalent to in mysql, IIRC). So you'll only get results that match on both sides, if there is a missing Governor then you'll lose that row, so one thing to try is a `LEFT JOIN` -- try something simple first:

```
USE prime_minister_2013;
SELECT ministry.pm_name, gg_name
FROM ministry
LEFT JOIN governor_general
ON governor_general.pm_name = ministry.pm_name ;
```

And see what that gets you (if there's a blank in gg_name in a row try it again with just `JOIN` to see that row disappear). You'll also see if there are PMs with two GGs.

From there it depends what results you're actually trying to get -- to get counts to be right you might want to do `COUNT(DISTINCT ministry.min_begin)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. The first will count the number of distinct times the ministry began (which will be the number or time that person was PM) rather than the number of matching rows.

There are a couple of other things to think about -- in your query you only group by one row, then other fields you select (`ministry.min_begin`, etc) will be (again, if I recall mysql correctly) randomly taken from a matching row -- which might not be what you want. So you might want to consider `MIN(ministry.min_begin)`, etc.

Finally, again it depends on your data, perhaps the data is storing the dates when things changes -- so for example if the PM changed but the GG stayed the same you may have several PM rows but only one GG row that covers all of them (and if this is an Australian question I think that's definitely the case). In that case you're going to need to have to do the JOIN on the intersection of the dates.

However, I think that should get you started, you can either update this question -- or if you have to try and match up dates you can search for other answers, or ask a separate question (btw, this answer looks promising: [MySQL - Finding time overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727400/mysql-finding-time-overlaps)).

Good luck.

**EDIT**

I can't test this from here but using the `LEFT JOIN` will get back your old row, however I *think* you need to be more clever. If you need a GG for each PM then you can't join the tables on just `pm_name` (because that's only the PM name when the GG started). It really depends on what the actual data you need is, one thing to do would be:

```
USE prime_minister_2013;
SELECT  ministry.pm_name, count(*) AS Number_times_PM, GG_name
  FROM ministry
  JOIN deputy_pm
    ON deputy_pm.min_nr = ministry.min_nr
  LEFT JOIN governor_general
    ON governor_general.GG_begin <= min_begin AND governor_general.GG_end >= min_begin
   AND ministry.party <> 'ALP'
   AND min_begin < '1930-01-01'
 GROUP by ministry.pm_name, GG_name;
```

But I think your data is deliberately made to be difficult, so it really depends what you're trying to find. You might need to do two queries (or one query with a sub-query) because you might want to know the PMs that had more than one GG under them over separate terms.

But if you play with the stuff above you can probably get somewhere.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your assistance. I will try and work through your suggestions Space Dog. I checked out finding time overlaps (thankyou) but I probably need a little more direction with that one! very new to queries!!

Comment: If you can edit your question to post an example of the data in the tables then we might be able to help more. Ideally, after narrowing down the problem rows as I explain above, then you could just post those a few rows to illustrate the problem. It's difficult to give any other advice with the info we currently have. And, I'll be honest, I've never actually had to make a time overlap query work in mysql before, which is why you might be better asking a separate question on that -- however you might not need to do that, I can't tell without seeing some of the data.

Comment: thank you. I tried to add sample tables - but it lost the formatting! I tried your suggestion & you are correct there are some PMs without GGs in the tables. I next tried your count distinct & that has sorted the count now.  How do I bring back the PM who does not have a GG?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` when you join the governors table -- that'll restore the missing row and give you a blank for the GG name. Apart from that it depends on the results you want, I'll have a look at it and edit my answer if I come up with anything.

Comment: PS - I only need the GG at the time they commenced office ( sorry missed explaining that!)

Comment: Ah, OK. My new query should do that (although I've missed some of the fields you were using on the SELECT). Although, like I said, I can't test from here so beware of typos, or me getting the <= / => the wrong way round.