# Finding overlapping intervals using SQL

Tags: sql

I want to extract rows from a table whose interval intersects with an interval specified in the query. Assuming that I have a simple `ID, DATE_START, DATE_END` table and two query parameters `P_DATE_START` and `P_DATE_END`, what is the simplest way of expressing the query so that I find all rows for which `[DATE_START, DATE_END]` has at least one common element with `[P_DATE_START, P_DATE_END]`?

---

Update:

To make the desired outcome clearer, please find a list of input values and expected outcomes below. Colums are  `DATE_START, DATE_END, P_DATE_START, P_DATE_END, MATCH`.

```
16, 17, 15, 18, YES
15, 18, 16, 17, YES
15, 17, 16, 18, YES
16, 18, 15, 17, YES
16, 17, 18, 19, NO
18, 19, 16, 17, NO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges/143568#143568

Comment: @Martin: this seems to be precisely what I'm looking for, thanks! I will vote to close my own question if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT id, date_start, date_end 
FROM thetable 
WHERE date_start <= p_date_end 
AND date_end >= p_date_start
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this as well. This does not work when `[date_start, date_end]` is completely contained in `[p_date_start, p_date_end]`.

Comment: @Robert, it does! For example, if [5,6] is completely contained in [1,10], then it's true that 5 <= 10 and 6 >= 1.

Comment: @Ilya : please see my question update. The check should be symmetric, i.e. if it works with the input `[5,6]` and row value `[1, 10]` it should work with the input `[1,10]` and row value `[5,6]`.

Comment: @Robert So can you give me an example of data on which this query fails?

Comment: Try the following (tested on MySQL) `create table intervals ( id bigint unsigned, date_start date, date_end date);

insert into intervals(id, date_start, date_end) VALUES ( 1, '2011-01-05', '2011-01-06'); 
select id from intervals where date_start <= '2011-01-01' and date_end >= '2011-01-10';`

Comment: @Robert, you confused p_date_start with p_date_end. It should be: `select id from intervals where date_start <= '2011-01-10' and date_end >= '2011-01-01'`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your dbms, you might be able to use the OVERLAPS operator.

```
select * from your_table
where (date '2011-01-15', date '2011-01-18') overlaps (date_start, date_end)
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT id, date_start, date_end 
        FROM thetable 
        WHERE not (date_end <  p_date_start
        OR    p_date_end < date_start )

Comment: Thanks, that was my first attempt. It does not solve the problem where `[p_date_start, p_date_end]` is completely contained in `[date_start, date_end]`. They intersect, but the query does not return.