# BETWEEN not working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I am implementing a hotel booking site where hotel owner can book rooms according to availability . For checking the number of rooms available , I have written the code like :

```
$q=" SELECT * 
        FROM  tbl_roombook
        WHERE
        hotel_id='$h_id'AND
        start_date
        BETWEEN  '$date1'
        AND  '$date2'
        AND end_date
        BETWEEN  '$date1'
        AND  '$date2'

    ";
$res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($q);
//var_dump($res);
```

In my database 2 rooms are booked from 2011-12-25 to 2011-12-31 . And my `echo $date1` is `2011-12-29` and `$echo date2` is `2011-12-30` . But `$q` returns empty results ! Why ?

Comment: What are the column types of `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: they are in date formate

Comment: Do you get any SQL errors? Does the query work in MySQL client or in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: The start date 111225 is not between 111229 and 111230

Comment: Try `start_date <= '$date2' AND end_date >= '$date1'` [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/143568/73226) for explanation.

Comment: Is there a `start_date` and `end_date` entry between `2011-12-29` and `2011-12-30`?

Comment: When debuging queries it's very useful to have a look at the mysql query log to actually see what gets executed. Your problem here is the MySQL query, and convoluting the question with PHP can only make the problem seem more complex.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave it should return no results...
start_date=2011-12-25 and is not between 2011-12-29 and 2011-12-30 so the expression is false right there.  I think what you want is to see if there is any overlap between the booked range and the new possible booking range right?

To do this you will want to instead check

```
start_date > '$date2' OR end_date < '$date1;
```

assuming that $date1 is always before $date2.

Answer (score 0):

The example will return no results for the `date1` and `date2` entries that u have provided.  That is because assuming your `start_date = 2011-12-25` and `end_date = 2011-12-31`.
None of both the values is within your provided date range  `2011-12-29 and 2011-12-30`.
Hence no result is generated. 
You could use it in reverse manner

```
'$date1' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date 
 OR  '$date2' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```