# Array loop performance when looking for duplicate/collisions

Tags: php, arrays, performance

This code loops though an array of events, each with a start and end time... and simply sets a 'match' key to say that it has matched another event (i.e. a collision to resolve):

```
<?php

$results = array(
        array('from' => 1, 'to' => 3),
        array('from' => 3, 'to' => 6),
        array('from' => 7, 'to' => 9),
        array('from' => 4, 'to' => 8),
    );

$k = 0;

foreach ($results as $p_id => $p_result) {

    foreach ($results as $c_id => $c_result) {
        if ($p_id == $c_id) {
            continue;
        }
        $k++;
        if ($p_result['from'] < $c_result['to'] && $p_result['to'] > $c_result['from']) {
            $results[$p_id]['match'] = $c_id;
            break;
        }
    }

}

print_r($results);
echo $k;

?>
```

By itself this isn't necessarily slow, but might be when thousands of events are being checked... i.e. using the DateTime object or UNIX timestamp for events though-out the year.

Trying with 3000 randomised events on my computer takes about 1 second with the "break" and 3 seconds without.

The to/from collision check itself is inspired by: [Comparing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552)

The main issue I see is that once event 1 has been checked against events 2-4, then events 2-4 don't really need to check themselves against 1:

```
$results[$p_id]['match'] = $c_id;
$results[$c_id]['match'] = $p_id;
```

But I can't think of an elegant way to work though this without making the code much harder to read.

One possibility is to create a new array of those events that have "passed" the checks, but I suspect the memory management of adding/removing elements on an array is much more than doing simple integer checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using foreach, you could use two numeric loops there. Then your 'inner loop' can start at the current `outer value+1`, and you wont process any double combinations.

```
$cachedCount = count($array);
for ($outer = 0; $outer < $cachedCount; $outer++){
  for ($inner = $outer+1; $inner< $cachedCount; $inner++){
    // process entries. no duplicates here. Only the ones that are dupplicates, 
    // but shouldn't be.
  }
}
```

i.e. assuming the array

```
0 -> "a"
1 -> "b"
2 -> "c"
3 -> "d"
```

it will have the following steps:

```
outer = 0; inner = 1; //a-b
outer = 0; inner = 2; //a-c
outer = 0; inner = 3; //a-d

outer = 1; inner = 2; //b-c
outer = 1; inner = 3; //b-d

outer = 2; inner = 3; //c-d
```

so all combinations are checked but no duplicate (`a-c` and `c-a`) or trivial combination (`a-a`, `b-b`) processed. Obviously for 2 Elements, it would start and end with comparing `0-1`. (Thats ONE comparission compared to 4 comparissions doing a 2by2 iteration (`1-1`, `1-2`, `2-1`, `2-2`)

Comment: Noticing a few updates there... I think your onto something... and one thing to change is the repeated calls to count(), that can be cached.

Comment: @CraigFrancis that can be cached yes. As the count function does not work without parameters, it is just a "verbal" example. ;)

Comment: just tested and getting 0.1 seconds now... thanks for updating to show the cachedCount (I know its irrational, but I hate seeing function calls in that bit of a for statement)... will do some more testing, but I think we have a winner.

Comment: @CraigFrancis Ignore the comment notification - it was correct :P

Comment: @CraigFrancis I like the way how you elaborated all given answers. This adds "quality" for all further visitors stumbling over the same question!

Comment: Hopefully it also shows I appreciate everyones time, and it makes me think though each answer to make sure I've not missed anything important :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use indices to adjust the size of the loops:

```
<?php
$arr = array( '1', '2', '3', '4' );
for($a=0; $a<count($arr); $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<$a; $b++){
        echo "compare: ".$arr[$a]." ".$arr[$b].",\n";
    }
}

//Ouput
//compare: 2 1,
//compare: 3 1,
//compare: 3 2,
//compare: 4 1,
//compare: 4 2,
//compare: 4 3,
```

http://codepad.org/BdxzvTvj

Mind you, while this is a good solution it will only provide 50% speed up. There are algorithmic changes which could dwarf the size of those gains.

Comment: Thanks @lemiant, unfortunately dognose managed to beat you by a few seconds... but thanks for helping, I don't think I should be allowed behind a keyboard this afternoon... also, minor tweak, but if you cache the count() function call, you can also save a few ms.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
foreach ($results as $p_id => $p_result) {
    foreach (array_slice($results, $p_id+1, NULL, true) as $c_id => $c_result) {
        if ($p_result['from'] < $c_result['to'] && $p_result['to'] > $c_result['from']) {
            $results[$p_id]['match'] = $c_id;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking good... while not particularly scientific thats 0.6 seconds (will also check the others)... now just wondering if the array_slice() could be replaced with an inner `for`, so we don't create a new set of arrays in memory?

Comment: Thanks Mark, while its basically the same as @dognose's solution, the use of the array_slice() slowed this solution down a bit... but thanks for the suggestion, certainly good having a second pair of eyes.