# booking dates ranges mysql php

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

Again booking system and dates ranges.
I've read this topic [Comparing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges) and many others,
but can't find answer :(

Please see SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89b2b/2

I have booking table, that have `ID`, `ObjectID`, `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd` fields of type `DATE` in `MySQL`
My example data looks like this:

```
(1, 3, '2014-08-07', '2014-08-14'),
(2, 3, '2014-08-19', '2014-08-23'),
(3, 2, '2014-08-13', '2014-08-15'),
(4, 2, '2014-08-19', '2014-08-21');
```

My query dates interval is (**updated**, was `$from = '2014-08-14';`):

```
$from = '2014-08-15';
$to = '2014-08-19'
```

I'd like to get `ObjectID`s that are *free* on query dates interval.
Problem is that, object's `2` first reservation ends on `2014-08-15` and we want to make new booking started from `2014-08-15`. Same thing with ending date `2014-08-19`. Existing reservations start on this day. It's ok for `humans` because we calculate date periods as `nights`, but how to tell same thing to `MySQL`?

For these variables

```
$from = '2014-08-15';
$to = '2014-08-19'
```

I'd like to get `[2, 3]` as the result of query.

For second query

```
$from = '2014-08-14';
$to = '2014-08-19'
```

I'd like to get only  `[3]` as the result of query, because ObjectID `2` is booked from `13 aug` to `15 aug`

Comment: `WHERE PeriodStart <= '2014-08-19' AND PeriodEnd >= '2014-08-14'` : Did I misunderstood your question or did you invert periodStart and periodEnd ?

Comment: Why would `2` be in the results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point. My mistake. :(

Answer (score 2):

The full code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectID
FROM booking
WHERE ObjectID IN
(
SELECT ObjectID
FROM booking
WHERE PeriodStart <= '2014-08-19' AND PeriodEnd >= '2014-08-14'
)
```

### #

```
+----------+
| OBJECTID |
+----------+
|        2 |
|        3 |
+----------+
```

#### Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89b2b/90

Comment: Thanks to @GordonLinoff he found mistake. How your query does right answer if object 2 has in database booking from 13 to 15 aug?
I have edited question and changed query period.

Comment: You want 13th to 15th or 15th to 19th?

Comment: I want correct results on any entered intervals. For query `14-19 aug` must be only one result `3`, and for query `15-19 aug` must be two results `[2, 3]`

Comment: Your data is confusing now... It has two rows with the same value. Object ID has different start date and end date. `:/`

Comment: please explain with more details. Object `3` has 2 bookings already. Object `2` has also 2 bookings. What same value?

Comment: Yup.. I was saying about the Object `3`. It has two bookings and it matches with the boundaries of the query. That's what I am confused. So we surely need a `Distinct()` function here.

Comment: Yes, it matches with the boundaries of the query, because we operate with human's term `night`. New booking may start `14 aug` and may end `19 aug`. But your `SQL` doesn't return right results :(

Comment: Sorry for the anachronistic comment but DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You just have a situation where the end date is not inclusive.  I would express the query as:

```
select b.objectid
from booking b
group by b.objectid
having sum(b.PeriodStart < '2014-08-19' and B.PeriodEnd > '2014-08-14') = 0
```

This counts the number of times there is a booking that covers the *nights* you care about.  If there are any, then the object is filtered out.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote on what appears to be working logic?  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89b2b/14)

Comment: Your query is fine in my opinion, or i really don't get what op wants. He says he wants objects 2, 3 in results, but object 2 has a booking during 2014-08-14 so..

Comment: @Logar thanks. My mistake. I want to query dates `14-19 aug` only ObjectID **3**, and for query `15-19 aug` both `[2, 3]`.
I've updated the question. Sorry for mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

This also seems working? am i missing anything in question

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ObjectID)
FROM booking
WHERE PeriodStart <= '2014-08-19' AND PeriodEnd >= '2014-08-14'
```

Comment: Oh, sorry senk - overlooked your answer - but note that DISTINCT is not a function!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectID
  FROM booking
 WHERE PeriodStart <= '2014-08-19' 
   AND PeriodEnd >= '2014-08-14';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89b2b/15

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with data provided your query return wrong result. We have for object `2` booked period from `13 aug` to `15 aug`. Please, see updated question.

Comment: This doesn't return 2 and 3? Now I'm confused. Maybe you need a more properly representative data set and desired result set.