# check conflict between two datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql

So I'm making a simple reservation system ,C# and sql .
I have datetimepicker 1 and datetimepicker 2 . 
For ex. datetimepicker = aug 1 2009  and datetimepicker2 = aug 3 2009 saved in sql by the user .

What to do with that so that the next customer that would try to get the date 1-3 would be forced to choose another date ?

Comment: This already has an answer; [the reference is MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges), but the technique is DB-agnostic (as the existing answer demonstrates).  Note that, given you should be [using an exclusive upper-bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges/143568#143568), it should be `NOT (range_start < @check_period_end ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query like this one:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from reservations t
where
not 
(

    (@dtTo <= t.DateFrom)

    or

    (@dtFrom >= t.DateTo)

)
```

assuming that @dtFrom, @dtTo are the dates the second user has chosen, and assuming
you have a `reservations` table with `DateFrom` and `DateTo` columns.

- If this query returns 0, then allow the second user to save.
- If it returns a number > 0, then don't allow the second user to save.

What's the idea behind this:
two segments of time `[dateFrom1, dateTo1]` and `[dateFrom2, dateTo2]` are not
conflicting (i.e. are not overlapping) for this reservation-based scenario if and only if:
`dateTo1 <= dateFrom2  or  dateFrom1 >= dateTo2`
(draw it on a piece of paper and you'll see why).
So if the negation
`not  (  dateTo1 <= dateFrom2  or  dateFrom1 >= dateTo2  )`
is true, the two segments are overlapping/conflicting.