# Evaluate mysql date range

Tags: mysql, range, date-range

I have a mysql table with some date ranges, for example:

```
start: 2015-09-10 end: 2015-09-10
```

Now, I have to check if another date range is inside the start-end date, even if only for some days.

1. 2015-09-02 -> 2015-09-03 is outside the range;
2. 2015-09-05 -> 2015-09-11 is inside the range;
3. 2015-09-11 -> 2015-09-12 is inside the range;
4. ...

I have these query, it works for case 1 and 2:

```
SELECT * FROM prenotazione WHERE id_stanza=1 AND (start BETWEEN '2015-09-11' AND '2015-09-12' and end BETWEEN '2015-09-11' AND '2015-09-12' )
```

For the case 3, the query returns no result, even id the given date are inside the range. 
Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges)

Comment: Dude please check the data it is not inside, result is correct between check like as **start<='2015-09-11' AND start<='2015-09-12** according to it it this condition is not satisfying

Comment: Dude please check the data it is not inside, result is correct between check like as **start('2015-09-10')<='2015-09-11' AND start('2015-09-10')<='2015-09-12'** according to it it this condition is not satisfying and same for 'end'

Comment: how does the 3rd date range lie between '2015-09-10' and '2015-09-10'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 1):

use `OR` to match either start or end

```
SELECT * FROM prenotazione 
WHERE id_stanza=1 AND
((`start` BETWEEN '2015-09-11' AND '2015-09-12') OR (`end` BETWEEN '2015-09-11' AND '2015-09-12'))
```