# PHP and MySQL: Comparing month and day with dynamic year

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-comparison

I am having a bit of trouble with an application I am working on and I hope to get some guidance.

I have a simple booking system: each item has a standard price, but there are some periods when the price can change.

For example:

- Standard price is **100/day**
- From `Oct. 1st` to `Feb. 1st` of each year, the price is **80/day**
- From `Jun. 1st` to `Aug. 31st` of each year the price is **120/day**
- [...] *up to 6 different price changes (seasons)*

Because this is a yearly occurrence, I only need the month and day, but I dont't know how to store these values in the database. I was thinking of having two fields, one for month and one for day which hold numeric values(`01-12` for month, `01-31` for day). These values are set by the user himself and they are relative to the item itself, it's not fixed for everyone.

The problem is that when someone makes a booking, I need to check if the price needs to be changed and I don't understand how to build the query to check this. To make maters worst, the price can have multiple values for a booked period.

Following the example above, If I were to book an item from `Sep. 1st (current year)` to `Jul. 1st (next year)`, the price will be as follow:

- **100/day** from `Sep. 1st` to `Sep. 30th`
- **80/day** from `Oct. 1st` to `Feb. 1st`
- **100/day** from `Feb. 2nd` `to May 31st`
- **120/day** from `Jun. 1st` to `Jul. 1st`

Is there any way of checking these cases without having to loop each day and checking against the database for a match ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your database tables, but I think you could do like this:

1. Get your period, iniDay, iniMonth, endDay, endMonth
2. Your table need to have these fields: ini_day, ini_month, ini_daymonth, end_day, end_month, end_daymonth, price_day
3. `SELECT * from table
   WHERE iniDay >= booking_ini_day AND iniMonth >= booking_ini_month -- get initial period
   AND iniDay <= booking_end_day AND iniMonth <= booking_end_month
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * from table
   WHERE iniDay <= booking_ini_day AND iniMonth <= booking_ini_month -- get middle periods
   AND endDay >= booking_end_day AND endMonth >= booking_end_month
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * from table
   WHERE 
   endDay >= booking_ini_day AND endMonth >= booking_ini_month
   AND endDay <= booking_end_day AND endMonth <= booking_end_month -- get end period`
4. Count days for each period/row in your result query and show to your user.

You will "duplicate" database information, like day, month and daymonth, but it's for better performance.

Comment: Currently my table is structured like you described except I don't have a field for month and day combined. I will make some tests right away and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. The dates a user books do not necessarily fall between a range, but only some days may, so the where clause is not correct.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. But seeing your query, what is the purpose of daymonth fields at this point if all the comparisons are made with single days and months ?

Comment: If you need to do another comparison, query, order by, group by, add year or just show that information, it will be already in your hand. No need to cast or concat data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL `date_format` function when checking date.

For example:

```
select date_format('2016-05-18', '%m%d');
+-----------------------------------+
| date_format('2016-05-18', '%m%d') |
+-----------------------------------+
| 0518                              |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)
```

So, you can just check with simple interval: today is `0518` and its betwen Feb. 2nd and May 31st:

> 0202 <= 0518 <= 0531

Complete example:

```
desc mytable;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date_from | char(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_to   | char(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

select * from mytable;
+-----------+---------+-------+
| date_from | date_to | price |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| 0901      | 0930    |   100 |
| 1001      | 0201    |    80 |
| 0202      | 0531    |   100 |
| 0601      | 0701    |   120 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Sample query:

```
select price, date_from, date_to from mytable where date_format(now(), '%m%d') between date_from and date_to;
+-------+-----------+---------+
| price | date_from | date_to |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   100 | 0202      | 0531    |
+-------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)
```

**EDIT**:

Read your comment on @FelipeDuarte's answer... For period from 10/01 (Oct. 1st) to 02/01 (Feb. 1st), we need to consider the new year...

You can cheat by splitting the period in two ones: 10/01 to 12/31 and 01/01 to 02/01

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. So now I can find the price for a certain date. But my problem is that I cannot find the price(s) for a date range. Are you suggesting I query each day ? So if I book 10 days, from Sep.01 to Sep.11, I'll have to loop 10 times and find the right price. Is this right ? I know performance will be kind of bad, but I am looking at most 30 days for a booking. Thank you again

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges) might be usefull.

Comment: But I understand your question is slightly different: if the given period overlaps two periods, there will be 2 different prices...

Comment: Yes, given a range the user wants to book an item, the price may be different on a day to day basis(worst case). Maybe two days it's 100, another two days is 80, three days is 150 and so on, depending on the total periods in the table. In the end I think I may just query each day and add the price: as I said, at most there will be maybe 30/40 days

Comment: Or maybe you can do it in a different way. Query all periods (with their daily price) and check the appropriate ones depending on the booking period. It should be much faster and easier to manipulate in PHP.