# MYSQL Find out if a date range falls in between another date range

Tags: php, mysql

Finding if a given single date is between a date period is pretty straight forward but say I have a start date and an end date, how do I query to see if any part of that date range falls in between another date range.

So find dbr_id WHERE any part of the period 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-30 is between the period 2016-12-04 to 2016-12-11?

Apologies for the lack of code, but as I say I can't think of anything remotely workable.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges

Comment: Bugger... thank you, don't know why I couldn't find this in an hour of searching.