# how to get data from database using date between?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Database stored date

```
item 1: date from :- 10-07-2017 date to :- 20-07-2017
item 2: date from :- 02-07-2017 date to :- 02-08-2017
item 3: date from :- 01-06-2017 date to :- 20-08-2017
```

input date

```
start date:- 05-07-2017 end date :- 25-07-2017
```

here I gave an input date to get data from database. database stored date is the data I want to print. thing is that, which are the items date included in the input date

condition 
this are the condition I want to work

```
start_date < date from && end_date > date_to 
start_date > date from && end_date > date_to 
start_date < date from && end_date < date_to 
start_date > date from && end_date < date_to
```

exception case

```
start_date < end_date < date_to
start_date > end_date > date_to
```

I want a codeignitor solution . below am giving my model class structure

```
public function getDate( $start_date = "",$end_date = """)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_details');
$this->db->where('');
}
```

table data
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npDtF.png)

Comment: And you tried what?

Comment: Store dates as dates

Comment: Just want to get data from database.I have some user details i gave some privilege to them based on the date duration so I am searching two date to get who all are the users are active in between the date. suppose start date is less than input start date , end date is greater than the start date so that user i want to be selected .. and conditions are given in the question

Comment: Probably the best way to solve your problem is here [Comparing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143568/5077564)

Comment: thank you ankit suthar its working .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
$this->db->where('sell_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
```

or try like that

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('');
$this->db->where('start_Date <','2012-10-03');
$this->db->where('end_Date >','2012-10-01');

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: what is sell_date?

Comment: its a column name for example

Comment: but i have multiple column . start_Date and end_date

Comment: give your full query what you want ?

Comment: Just want to get data from database.I have some user details i gave some privilege to them based on the date duration so I am searching two date to get who all are the users are active in between the date. suppose start date is less than input start date , end date is greater than the start date so that user i want to be selected .. and conditions are given in the question

Comment: start_date < end_date < date_to
start_date > end_date > date_to except these two condition that i want to be worked

Comment: can you provide table structure?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `64_user_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: You have to run different queries for different purpose.

Comment: Its not possible in only in one query, not get the right result(i think).

Answer (score 0):

use date between(...)
or date>date1 and date