Date comparison to find missing dates
I am trying to compare dates to find when someone is no longer eligible. In this sample they are not eligible from 10/1/23 to 10/19/23. So the 9/30/23 exp_date to the 10/20/23 eff_date. How do I find that range? Thanks.

CREATE TABLE ADMITS
(
ID_NUM INT
,AUTH_EFF_DATE  date null
,AUTH_EXP_DATE  date null
,MEM_EFF_DATE   date null
,MEM_EXP_DATE date null

)

INSERT INTO ADMITS (ID_NUM,AUTH_EFF_DATE,AUTH_EXP_DATE,MEM_EFF_DATE,MEM_EXP_DATE)
VALUES
 (118206307, '1/2/2023', '6/7/2023', '4/22/2022', '9/30/2023')
,(118206307, '8/30/2023', '2/17/2024', '4/22/2022', '9/30/2023')
,(118206307, '1/2/2023', '6/7/2023', '10/20/2023', '12/31/9999')
,(118206307, '8/30/2023', '2/17/2024', '10/20/2023', '12/31/9999')
;

From that I'd like to compare that date range to the auth_eff_date and auth_exp_date to show what auth ranges had missing eligibilities. I thought maybe lead or lag but wasn't sure how or if that was right.

what is the wanted result?

@nbk...i'd like to show the id_num, 8/30/23,2/17/24, then what missing dates, the 10/1/23, and 10/19/23.

Your data already appears to be a cross join between AUTH dates and MEM dates.  I suggest that you post the original data before it has already processed it through a (possibly poorly constructed) query.

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges

Multiple solutions have been proposed. Please provide more examples so we can validate the soultions, identify edge cases, and evaluate performance.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

The first step is using LAG as you suggested to find when someone is no longer eligible and the authorization range. Then we can apply the range comparisons strategy suggested by Comparing date ranges
WITH Previous as
(  
 SELECT *,
   LAG(MEM_EXP_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_NUM ORDER BY MEM_EFF_DATE,AUTH_EFF_DATE)  as PrevExprDate,
   LAG(AUTH_EFF_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_NUM ORDER BY MEM_EFF_DATE,AUTH_EFF_DATE)  as PrevAUTH_EFF_DATE,
   LAG(AUTH_EXP_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_NUM ORDER BY MEM_EFF_DATE,AUTH_EFF_DATE)  as PrevAUTH_EXP_DATE
 FROM ADMITS
),
Eligible as
(  
SELECT *,
    CASE 
     WHEN PrevExprDate IS NULL THEN NULL 
     WHEN PrevExprDate = '12/31/9999' THEN '12/31/9999'
     ELSE DateAdd(day, 1, PrevExprDate) END as StartNotEligible,
    CASE 
     WHEN MEM_EFF_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL 
     WHEN MEM_EFF_DATE = '12/31/9999' THEN '12/31/9999'
     ELSE DateAdd(day, -1, MEM_EFF_DATE) END as EndNotEligible
FROM Previous
)
Select ID_NUM, PrevAUTH_EFF_DATE, PrevAUTH_EXP_DATE, StartNotEligible,EndNotEligible 
FROM Eligible 
WHERE (StartNotEligible <= PrevAUTH_EXP_DATE      AND EndNotEligible >= PrevAUTH_EFF_DATE)

fiddle
Intermediate:



ID_NUM
AUTH_EFF_DATE
AUTH_EXP_DATE
MEM_EFF_DATE
MEM_EXP_DATE
PrevExprDate
StartNotEligible
EndNotEligible




118206307
2023-01-02
2023-06-07
2022-04-22
2023-09-30
null
null
2022-04-21


118206307
2023-08-30
2024-02-17
2022-04-22
2023-09-30
2023-09-30
2023-10-01
2022-04-21


118206307
2023-01-02
2023-06-07
2023-10-20
9999-12-31
2023-09-30
2023-10-01
2023-10-19


118206307
2023-08-30
2024-02-17
2023-10-20
9999-12-31
9999-12-31
9999-12-31
2023-10-19



Final:



ID_NUM
PrevAUTH_EFF_DATE
PrevAUTH_EXP_DATE
StartNotEligible
EndNotEligible




118206307
2023-08-30
2024-02-17
2023-10-01
2023-10-19




The first step is to separate out and dedup the authorization and eligibility data. The original posted data provided appears to be a cross apply of the two, possibly from an earlier query.
The second step is to calculate exclusive end dates by adding 1 day to the inclusive end dates provided in the data. Date range and overlap calculations just work better with a combination of inclusive start dates and exclusive end dates that form half-open intervals. A combination of NULLIF() and ISNULL() is used to preserve the special end-of-time 9999-12-31 values.
In the code below, I use the term ThruDate to refer to the inclusive end date (for display only), and ToDate to refer to the exclusive end date (used by the logic).
Next we need to identify all distinct date ranges to be tested. This can be done by extracting all distinct start and exclusive-end dates, sorting them, and then constructing new date ranges for each interval. The LAG() window function is used to get the prior date to be combined with the current data to define each range.
Now we can test each date interval for overlaps with the authorization and eligibility date ranges. A standard test for overlapping date ranges is Start1 < End2 AND Start2 < End1. If our sample interval overlaps an authorization row, but does not overlap an eligibility row, we have identified an authorized but ineligible interval to be included in the results.
All calculations are done independently for each ID value.
The resulting logic would be something like:
-- Date range operations work much better when using "exclusive" end dates,
-- so we will calculate and use exclusive end dates for all range and overlap
-- logic, and only use the inclusive end dates for display.
--
-- To see the intermediate results:
--    Change the select to SELECT * and
--    Uncomment the WHERE clause.
WITH AuthDates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT -- Distinct is used here to dedup the original unnormalized data
        ID_NUM AS Id,
        AUTH_EFF_DATE AS AuthFromDate,
        AUTH_EXP_DATE AS AuthThruDate, -- Inclusive
        ISNULL(
            DATEADD(day, 1, NULLIF(AUTH_EXP_DATE, '9999-12-31')),
            '9999-12-31') AS AuthToDate -- Exclusive
    FROM ADMITS
),
EligibilityDates AS ( -- Distinct is used here to dedup the original unnormalized data
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ID_NUM AS Id,
        MEM_EFF_DATE AS EligFromDate,
        MEM_EFF_DATE AS EligThruDate, -- Inclusive
        ISNULL(
            DATEADD(day, 1, NULLIF(MEM_EXP_DATE, '9999-12-31')),
            '9999-12-31') AS EligToDate -- Exclusive
    FROM ADMITS
),
DistinctDates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT U.Id, U.Date
    FROM (
        SELECT A.Id, V.Date
        FROM AuthDates A
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (AuthFromDate), (AuthToDate)) V(Date)
        UNION ALL  -- (Yes, I could drop the ALL, but I prefer an explicit DISTINCT)
        SELECT E.Id, V.Date
        FROM EligibilityDates E
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (EligFromDate), (EligToDate)) V(Date)
    ) U
),
DateRanges AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date)  AS FromDate,
        ISNULL(
            DATEADD(day, -1, NULLIF(Date, '9999-12-31')),
            '9999-12-31') AS ThruDate,
        Date AS ToDate
    FROM DistinctDates
)
SELECT
    A.Id,
    A.AuthFromDate, A.AuthThruDate,
    D.FromDate AS IneligibleFromDate, D.ThruDate AS IneligibleThruDate
FROM DateRanges D
LEFT JOIN AuthDates A
    ON A.Id = D.Id
    AND A.AuthFromDate < D.ToDate
    AND A.AuthToDate > D.FromDate
LEFT JOIN EligibilityDates E
    ON E.Id = D.Id
    AND E.EligFromDate < D.ToDate
    AND E.EligToDate > D.FromDate
WHERE A.ID IS NOT NULL  -- Authorized
AND E.Id IS NULL        -- But not eligible
ORDER BY
    D.Id,
    D.FromDate

(The current WHERE conditions could be eliminated by changing the first LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN and changing the second LEFT JOIN to a WHERE NOT EXISTS(...) subselect, but I have left them as outer joins so that intermediate results can be easily viewed.)
Intermediate results (using exclusive end-dates):



Id
FromDate
ToDate
AuthFromDate
AuthToDate
EligFromDate
EligToDate




118206307
null
2022-04-22
null
null
null
null


118206307
2022-04-22
2023-01-02
null
null
2022-04-22
2023-10-01


118206307
2023-01-02
2023-06-08
2023-01-02
2023-06-08
2022-04-22
2023-10-01


118206307
2023-06-08
2023-08-30
null
null
2022-04-22
2023-10-01


118206307
2023-08-30
2023-10-01
2023-08-30
2024-02-18
2022-04-22
2023-10-01


118206307
2023-10-01
2023-10-20
2023-08-30
2024-02-18
null
null


118206307
2023-10-20
2024-02-18
2023-08-30
2024-02-18
2023-10-20
9999-12-31


118206307
2024-02-18
9999-12-31
null
null
2023-10-20
9999-12-31



Final results:



Id
AuthFromDate
AuthThruDate
IneligibleFromDate
IneligibleThruDate




118206307
2023-08-30
2024-02-17
2023-10-01
2023-10-19



See this db<>fiddle for a demo that includes additional test data covering multiple overlapping authorization and eligibility scenarios.
